# Java regex removing characters when specified not to

Tags: java, regex

I have java code that is cleaning xml code and removing any bad characters. This is my regex:

```
Pattern pt = Pattern.compile("[^a-zA-Z0-9()\\’\\.\\,\\-\\%]");
```

I specify that I want `’` to be included in the final text but it keeps getting replaced by a space. Am I not specifying the correct character?

The `logger.info` line is registering `’` as a space and replacing it.

**Code**

```
Pattern pt = Pattern.compile("[^a-zA-Z0-9()\\’\\.\\,\\-\\%]");
        Matcher match = pt.matcher(trim);
        while (match.find()) {
            String s = match.group();
            logger.info(s);
            trim = trim.replaceAll("\\" + s, " ");

        }
        return trim.trim();
```

**Input**
The
 State Service Commission’s...

**Output**
The State Service Commission s...

Comment: You don't need to escape all those characters. You can use `[^a-zA-Z0-9()’.,%-]` instead.

Comment: I tried your code, and giving it `The State Service Commission’s...` as input didn't produce that output. [Demo](https://ideone.com/LGqvgQ)

Comment: Your regex and code will be replacing space character with space character, by the way.

Comment: @BackSlash, must be that he's testing with another apostrophe-looking char.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should succeed when you edit *and* compile with UTF-8.

Use `\u2019` instead of `’`. And remove the spurious `\\` where not needed, as commented.

What I think that happens is that the quote gets mapped to an ASCII apostrophe in your default encoding (or maybe even a question mark?).

There are also Unicode awareness flags in regex, `(?u)` and `(?U)` but here I think it is simply a matter of a charset conversion somewhere.

Comment: When I add that to the regex: `[^a-zA-Z0-9().,%-\\u2019]` it replaces the character with a question mark like you mentioned instead of rendering it. I tried also adding a clause in the `while` loop saying `trim = trim.replaceAll("\\u2019" + s, "'");` but it still didn't pick it up.

Comment: THEN THIS PART WORKS. That means that the string on output is converted to some charset incapable to represent that quote. Like ISO-8859-1 (Latin-1). Windows-1252 (Windows Latin-1) could do it. If you are using Latin-1 in a web browser, you could as well use Windows-1252, as all browser interprete ISO-8859-1 as Windows-1252.